# How to use a Windows filename with a colon with Java 9 unified logging?

Tags: java, windows, logging, java-9

```
% java11 -Xlog:gc*:file=c:\max.txt -version
[0.002s][error][logging] Invalid decorator '\max.txt'.
Invalid -Xlog option '-Xlog:gc*:file=c:\max.txt', see error log for 
details.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Apparently with Java 9 (and later) unified logging a colon is used as a separator between fields in the `-Xlog` arguments. So, how do I specify a Windows pathname that has a colon in it? Is there an escape of some kind? If I specify the filename as is, I get the error I included above. Thank you.

Comment: Try "c:/max.txt"

Comment: Same result. It's the colon that is the issue.

Comment: Try c\:/max.txt or c\\:/max.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the ways suggested for solving that [on the mailing list](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdk9-dev/2017-August/005950.html) is using shell escapes like:

```
java -Xlog:gc*:file=\"C:\max.txt\" -version
```

Note that according to Dave Holmes' posting, only double quotes are supported.  Depending on the shell, the escaping is necessary so that the Java command sees the quotes.